# How to apply a function to several variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I need to check multiple variables, and call the same function on them

```
if isinstance(VarA,complex):
    VarA=SomeFunction(VarA)
if isinstance(VarB,complex):
    VarB=SomeFunction(VarB)
if isinstance(VarC,complex):
    VarC=SomeFunction(VarC)
```

Is possible to write this code in a shorter/more readable way?

Comment: May functional languages do not allow variable reassignment like `x = f(x)` and so your program would be invalid

Comment: @user633183 I didn't put the functional-programming tag. Only Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
a, b, c = (f(x) if isinstance(x, complex) else x for x in [a, b, c])
```

This becomes uglier when there are more than three variables, so, if you find yourself in need for lots of variables that are used to perform the same computation, you should think about using lists and loops:

```
List = [1, 2, 3 + 1j, 4, 5 - 2j]

processed = [f(x) if isinstance(x, complex) else x for x in List]
```

Comment: Nice solution for a *small* number of items.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a dictionary to hold your variable number of variables.

Then iterate your dictionary and modify values if your condition is satisfied.

```
vars = {'A': VarA, 'B': VarB, 'C': VarC}

for k, v in vars.items():
    if isinstance(v, complex):
        vars[k] = SomeFunction(vars[k])
```

Comment: I choose the other answer, because I have a small number of variables, but your answer is also good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
varA,varB,varC = (SomeFunction(var) if isinstance(var,complex) else var for var in [varA,varB,varC])
```